# Change Header View iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, button, view, uiviewcontroller

I have looked around for an answer and came up with this code.  I am trying to insert a picture into the header view (where words normally would be).

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 90.0)];

    UIImageView *i=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE NAME"]];

    [customView addSubview:i];

    return customView;

}
```

The table view header remains blank.

Any ideas? I'm just starting out here...Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified your image is loading properly into your image view?

Comment: Yes.  It was loading in before but not in the header view.  It loaded in over the cells (it covered the first cell and went into the second cell a little bit.  there was a white line where the second cell started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [Apple Developer UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

The returned object can be a UILabel or UIImageView object, as well as a custom view. This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.
Try that.

Comment: -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 90;
}

Still nothing...Do I need to specify the section if I only have one? Thanks

Comment: That's not necessary. Rightnow, don't add an image, rather set the background colour of customView to some colour and check if the customView is loaded properly. If it does, then check the same with an image of 320*90 resolution.

Comment: I got it to load in (the picture too), but it does not load it into the header. It loads it in right below the header (normally where the text would go is still visible).

How do I remove the blank header (Or insert my picture into it?)

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of what you are getting right now ?
This is the screenshot of what I got from your code (after inserting this line: i.frame = customView.frame; just before [customView addSubview:i];): http://www.mediafire.com/i/?zs83ms0i1bb8let. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thats what I was getting too.  Instead of using a UINavigationController, I used a UITableView and I got the picture to show up in the right place.  Now I can't get my cells to show up! One step at a time I guess.  Ill post back if I can't figure it out. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

That works perfectly for me:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 90;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIImageView *i = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE NAME"]];
    i.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 90.0);
    return [customView autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set a frame for the UIImageView, eg:
    i.frame = customView.frame;

Comment: Still nothing...I put in the code you gave (    i.frame = customView.frame;
)